# Chrome Extension for PouchDB with the unlimitedStoraged permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pouchdb

Chrome's storage limits are blocking my PouchDB scenarios. I'm hoping to use Chrome's [unlimited storage type](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#unlimited). To get around the storage limitations.

To enable this storage mode, I've defined a Chrome extension granting `unlimitedStorage` to my domain. Here is the manifest.json:

```
 {
  "name": "Extension Granting Unlimited Storage",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://localhost:5988/*"
      ],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["unlimitedStorage"]
}
```

This grants 100% of available storage to the extension's `background.js`, but there is no change to the storage limit accessed directly from content_scripts or my webpage's scripts. I'm thinking to import PouchDB into background.js and "forward" the PouchDB calls from my page to the extension via [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Similar for the result of the calls. Through this, the actual IndexedDB storage will take place in the extension's unlimited storage container.

I'm wondering if there is a better approach to solve this, or if it has been solved already. Also - whether it seems reasonable to implement as a PouchDB plugin.

Comment: Extension's storage isn't limited at least over the last several years (except chrome.storage.sync which is always limited) so unlimitedStorage only affects host apps, but those are completely different things. In other words, there's nothing you can do in an extension to alter an arbitrary web site's quota. Your idea with using the background page seems to be the only solution.

Comment: I tested this concept and wrote a library @ https://github.com/kennsippell/pouchdb-unlimited-storage. The concept works well. Limited to 128 MB per request so can fail with `allDocs` etc. - maybe it will be useful to somebody at some point.

Comment: Yeah, 128MB is the Chrome's IPC messaging limit.